# Efficient GroupBy/CombineBy in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am using Spark (pyspark with Spark version 1.6) and I have a DataFrame like:

```
DataFrame[clientId: bigint, clientName: string, action: string, ...]
```

I want to dump it in S3 segregated by an attribute (e.g. `clientId`) in the following format `s3://path/<clientId>/<datafiles>`.

I want the `datafiles` to contain the rows for the corresponding `clientId` in json format, so for the path `s3://path/1/`, the datafiles will contain:

```
{"clientId":1, "clientName":"John Doe", "action":"foo", ...}
{"clientId":1, "clientName":"John Doe", "action":"bar", ...}
{"clientId":1, "clientName":"John Doe", "action":"baz", ...}
```

I was thinking on using `groupBy` then a `toJSON` but in DataFrames you can only collect the data and the DataFrame is too big to fit in the driver (also the I/O is massive). How can I save the partial results of the group from the executors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `partitionBy` and write to JSON:

```
df.write.partitionBy("clientName").json(output_path)
```

You'll get structure

```
s3://path/clientId=some_id/<datafiles>
```